# ERROR: bad DVC file name 'my_server\models\*.tar.gz.dvc' is git-ignored

Tags: git, dvc

I just started with DVC. I have a git repo in which there are heavy models that i want to push to dvc. So I initialized the dvc by

```
dvc init
```

and then configured the bucket

```
dvc remote add -d storage s3://mybucket/dvcstore
```

Now there is `/models` folders, in which there was `.gitkeep` file and trained models. Following entry was in my `.gitignore`

```
*.tar.gz
```

I ran the following command

```
git rm -r --cached my_server\models
```

and added the following in the `.gitignore`

```
models
```

I want to add all the `tar.gz` files to push on dvc

so i tried

```
dvc add ./my_server/models/*.tar.gz
```

but this is showing

```
ERROR: bad DVC file name 'my_server\models\*.tar.gz.dvc' is git-ignored.
```

If I do
dvc add ./my_server/models/

then this folder is added and a `models.dvc` file gets created. then git code shows for the changes.

what is the correct way, do i need to mention `*.dvc` to `.gitignore` as well?

Comment: Tags should be created [when there's a *very* good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). In this case, [dvc] gives you enough coverage.

Answer (score 4):

You can add

```
models/*
!models/*.dvc
```

to `.gitignore` to ignore other files in models/ except for `.dvc` files.

`dvc add` will automatically add the dvc tracked files to `.gitignore`

In most cases, you needn't to manage `.gitignore` you self.

Comment: `dvc add` added .dvc file that git is showing in un tracked changes, .dvc files will be commited to git?

Answer (score 0):

I added a git ignore for all file endings that aren't dvc (which were just 2 endings in my case).

So in your case I would create a .gitignore file in

```
./my_server/models/
```

with:

```
*.tar.gz
```